# How to access url path in django view

Tags: django

How can I access the url in a Django view. I have a view handling following 5 urls:

```
localhost:8000/standings/
localhost:8000/standings/q1
localhost:8000/standings/q2
localhost:8000/standings/q3
localhost:8000/standings/q4
```

and my view is

```
class StandingsView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'standings.html'
```

Based on `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4` or `None` in the url path, I have to query data from the db and render to the given template.

Please suggest on how such scenarios can be handled.

Comment: Can you share the url config for this view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the path with `self.request.path`:

```
class StandingsView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'standings.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        path = self.request.path
        # …
        return context
```

But processing the path might be cumbersome and error prone. You can define five urls here in the `urls.py` and inject values in the kwargs, like:

```
from django.urls import path

from app.views import StandingsView

urlpatterns = [
    path('standings/', StandingsView.as_view(), kwargs={'q': None}),
    path('standings/q1', StandingsView.as_view(), kwargs={'q': 1}),
    path('standings/q2', StandingsView.as_view(), kwargs={'q': 2}),
    path('standings/q3', StandingsView.as_view(), kwargs={'q': 3}),
    path('standings/q4', StandingsView.as_view(), kwargs={'q': 4})
]
```

Then you can access the added kwargs in `self.kwargs['q']`:

```
class StandingsView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'standings.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        q = self.kwargs['q']
        # …
        return context
```

You might however want to take a look at a [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) that can implement most of the boilerplate logic.

Comment: What if I want to send the other urls(i.e. except the one that is called out) to the template to be shown as links on the UI? I can explicitly define the other urls and add them to a list and update the context with this list but that doesn't seems to be a good approach.